# How to disable cell to cell navigation on arrow down key in ui grid of angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using a editable cell in ui-grid it has cell-nav enabled, and when I am editing the cell arrow keys causing to move another cell rather than with in editable cell navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Design, if you click inside the cell while in edit, it will go into 'deep edit'.  This lets you then use the arrow keys to navigate the input text.  If this is not happening after you click inside the text box, please file a bug report on Github. https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues